# How to store data in Powerbi for custom visual except active local storage api

Tags: powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to store user inputs to the external cloud server. But i call the api request, it will be blocked by visual's sandbox csp (Content Security Policy). I don't solve this issue. Please help me. Thanks.

```js
setData = async (data: string): Promise<void> => {
        let url = "https://myitanalyticsdiag.blob.core.windows.net/bootdiagnostics-eusvm01-5fe205b2-e051-435a-b406-12efdd05a96a?sp=racwdli&st=2022-07-18T02:50:01Z&se=2022-07-30T10:50:01Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=i0xaDxZ2jA5WA68Vh89B5tIlYJaDS4WWlgKQ%2F9kUUrs%3D"; // URL with SAS token
        if (url) {
            try {
                let resp = await fetch(url, {
                    referrer: "https://app.powerbi.com",
                    headers: {
                        "x-ms-version": "2017-11-09",
                        "x-ms-date": new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0],
                        "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
                        "x-ms-blob-content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\"mydata.txt\"",
                        "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
                        "x-ms-meta-m1": "v1",
                        "x-ms-meta-m2": "v2",
                        "Authorization": "sp=racwdli&st=2022-07-18T02:50:01Z&se=2022-07-30T10:50:01Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=i0xaDxZ2jA5WA68Vh89B5tIlYJaDS4WWlgKQ%2F9kUUrs%3D" // not needed with sas token
                    },
                    method: "PUT",
                    body: data
                });
                return Promise.resolve();
            } catch (err) {
                return Promise.reject("Request failed.");
            }
        }
        return Promise.reject("No save url defined.");
    }
```

[Issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT7He.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the new Permission API available in v4.7.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/permissions-api

Basically, you need to provide the URL capabilities.json, this way Power BI will add an exception to the visual iframe:

```
"privileges": [
    {
        "name": "WebAccess",
        "essential": true,
        "parameters": [
            "https://myitanalyticsdiag.blob.core.windows.net/"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Do I need to send email to Microsoft Support team in order to apply for this service permission?

Comment: No, you don't need any permission from Microsoft for that. This feature will probably show an alert to the Power BI admins in the future and they will be able to block the access to the resource, if they want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems help me. I'll try it.

Comment: I'm try to do like this. But it also doesn't work. If I add this url with localhost address , it can be work. Otherwise not.  Do you know how to solve it ?